# Ребинд выбора подсказки в vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Выскакивают подсказки в vscode. Мне приходится выбирать нужную стрелочками. Как это перебиндить?
Пробовал искать в настройках кейбиндов, но поиск ни к чему не привел.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение. Просто перебиндил стрелочки в настройках вскода. Только теперь не получится ими пользоваться вовсе:)

Comment: Месье знает толк... :Р